# Check if words in string array ends and starts with char and insert new string between them (c#)

Tags: c#, string, linq, list, cycle

How can I insert a string between two strings if a condition is true?

Let's say we have an array of characters that we want to check if the first word ends with one of them and the second word starts with one of them.

For example "Go home" will pass the condition because "o" and "h" are letters that will meet requirement (=> Go ___ home)

```
char[] toCheck = {'h','o','d', 'g'};
string sentence = "Go home";

List<string> words = sentence.Split(' ').ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < words.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (toCheck.Any(x=> x == words[i][words[i].Length - 1]) &&
           (toCheck.Any(x=> x == words[i + 1][0])))
        {
             words.Insert(i,"_between");
        }
    }

return words.Aggregate("", (current, word) => current + (word + " "));
```

My problem is that this is returning "_between Go _between home" instead of "Go _between home" and I can't find out why.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You could do `x == words[i].Last()` instead of `x == words[i][words[i].Length - 1]` which IMO is more readable.  And use `return string.Join(" ", words);` for combining the words back together.

Comment: In your `if` condition, add `i > 0 &&`. This should fix you up. Make sure its the first condition in your `if`. Or, better yet, change your `for` loop to `for (int i = 1; i < words.Count - 1; i++)`. Since you never want `_between` to go before the first word, start the loop at 1.

Comment: The problem is that the length of `words` is going to keep growing since you are adding values to it.  It's best to not mutate a collection you are looping over for that reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method you could use to do this that will return a sequence of the words instead of inserting into the original collection.

```
private static IEnumerable<string> InsertBetween(
    this IList<string> words, 
    char[] characters, 
    string insertValue)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < words.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        yield return words[i];
        if (characters.Contains(words[i].Last()) && characters.Contains(words[i + 1][0]))
            yield return insertValue;
    }

    if (words.Count > 0)
        yield return words[words.Count - 1];
}
```

Then running this

```
char[] toCheck = { 'h', 'o', 'd', 'g' };
string sentence = "Go home";
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", sentence.Split().InsertBetween(toCheck, "_between")));
```

Will give you

> Go _between home

I just think it's better to avoid mutating a colleciton that you are looping over, but if you do you need to increment the index when you do an insert so you move past the inserted value and you have to insert in the correct position.

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (toCheck.Any(x => x == words[i][words[i].Length - 1]) &&
        (toCheck.Any(x => x == words[i + 1][0])))
    {
        words.Insert(i + 1, "_between");
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! At the end, this method is the most suitable in my case, so I am accepting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider doing it a very straight-forward way by having the resulting sentence stored in a new `string`:

```
char[] toCheck = { 'h', 'o', 'd', 'g' };
string sentence = "Go home";

string finalsentence = "";

List<string> words = sentence.Split(' ').ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < words.Count - 1; i++) {
    if (toCheck.Any(x => x == words[i][words[i].Length - 1]) &&
         (toCheck.Any(x => x == words[i + 1][0]))) {
             finalsentence = words[i] + "_between" + words[i + 1] + " ";
    }
}

return finalsentence;
```

That being said, if you want to make your current method words, you should refer to insert in index `i + k` (with incremented `k` starting from `1`, thanks to juharr) rather than `i` and using `string.Join`, not `aggregate`:

```
char[] toCheck = { 'h', 'o', 'd', 'g' };
string sentence = "Go home";
int k = 1;

List<string> words = sentenc;e.Split(' ').ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < words.Count - 1; i++) {
    if (toCheck.Any(x => x == words[i][words[i].Length - 1]) &&
         toCheck.Any(x => x == words[i + 1][0])) {
             words.Insert(i + k++, "_between");
    }
}

return string.Join(" ", words);
```

Comment: Or better yet a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @juharr or `string.Join` ... ;)

Comment: When a word is inserted then `i` needs to be incremented or if one of the characters is the last letter in the inserted word it would result in an infinite loop.

Comment: @juharr very nice observation for the second method (using `Insert`). Updated.

Answer (score 0):

"My problem is that this is returning "_between Go _between home" instead of "Go _between home" and I can't find out why."

Because yours i index in `words.Insert(i,"_between");` is starting from 0. You could change the code on many ways, but based on your question, if you want to keep it, just don't `words.Insert(i,"_between");` for i==0.

Hope this helps...